# Why can't I install Steam onto Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit or 64-bit version?

Tags: installation, 12.10, steam

At first I had installed a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 7 Premium. When I tried installing Steam onto Ubuntu from the Steam client, I got an error message stating `Wrong architecture 'i386'`.

Then I tried installing Steam through Ubuntu Software Center, and I got one message saying that "Package dependencies cannot be resolved: This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."

I also had another message stating, "The application Ubuntu Software Center has experienced and internal error. There was an error submitting the transaction"

Since the Software Center said "Steam (64-bit)", I figured that I should have installed the 64-bit version instead of the 32-bit version. So, I uninstalled my previous Ubuntu and installed the 64-bit version, which if I'm correct is **amd64** and not **i386**.

I tried installing Steam through the website and Software Center again and still the same messages appear. I would appreciate some help on the choice between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of 12.10 (if I'm not mistaken, 12.10 is the newest version of Ubuntu),or anything else I can do to fix this.

I hope to get this resolved, as this is my first experience with Ubuntu and I'm really liking this OS (aside from the problem I'm dealing with now.)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/257084/44179

Answer (score 0):

There are 32-bit versions of Steam. I think you may have to re-install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, depending on whether your hardware is 32-bit or 64-bit.

12.10 is the latest version of Ubuntu, but it isn't the most stable. I would recommend using 12.04 LTS (The LTS stands for "Long Term Support"). It's the most stable version of Ubuntu (LTS versions are the most stable). Valve built Steam for Linux to work with 12.04, so getting it to work on 12.10 may be a bit of a challenge if you're not familiar with Ubuntu.

I assure you that you aren't losing anything by going to 12.04 LTS.

Are you able to tell us what your hardware is, so we can tell you whether you should be running 32-bit Ubuntu or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't answered any questions or gave any more info, I was away from my computer for a while. Anyways, I downloaded a 32-bit version of 12.04. The download for Steam has gotten less buggy since I last tried, and I downloaded it from the Steam client with no trouble.

Comment: Also, sorry for the duplicate. I guess I just didn't see what I thought I was looking for in the other questions about Steam on Ubuntu.