# How do I install steam on a 64bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, steam

Alright so my computer is 64-bit and I only want to use Linux to install Steam, play *Team Fortress 2* and get that penguin item but It's not working out for me. The version of Ubuntu I installed was the "Wubi.exe" which let's me use it along with Windows. But when I get it up and download the Steam .deb file, it tells me "Wrong Architecture 'i386'". What do I have to do to run Ubuntu alongside windows without using a CD/USB stick?

Comment: Similar question: [How can I install Steam?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1784/176889)

Answer (score 15):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Try installing it after doing that.

For future reference look: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch

Comment: still doesnt work for me

Comment: It worked fine here when I've ran into the problem. (And It's the way many people fixed it)

Comment: @user132730 after doing that run sudo apt-get install ia32-libs as has been suggested by lordqwerty.

Comment: recent versions of Ubuntu supports multiarch natively (both precise and trusty), you just need to apt-get install steam.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT [Preferred Method on new Ubuntu]**

As of Ubuntu 16.04 you can now do the following:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt-get install steam
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Try installing the `ia32 libs` by opening up a terminal and entering the following:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once that has run and installed, then use terminal to install Steam for you. Run the following in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install steam
```

Now you will have Steam installed and you should be able to launch it as expected.

Comment: This answer is the second part of the solution. First you need to add the i386 architecture... see https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1093819 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/1016294/comments/27

Comment: And don't use the steam.deb on the steam website...

Comment: @jblemee Yeah, I tried that and it was complete garbage. Now I know why they have a clause in the license allowing the modification of startup scripts and such for the Linux version.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install steam
```

it's working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on iMac 2008 via Dual-boot with rEFInd.

Comment: Thank you i was looking for the solution for 14.04 64bit everywhere. Yours worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about in 14.04, but at least in 15.04 steam is in the multiverse repository.  that means that you can simply sudo apt-get install steam and it will install the required dependencies.  No need to download a .deb file.

Just adding this for future use.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get -f install steam
```

This worked for me, finally after searching around for a few hours.  Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Talk of i386 or ia32-libs doesn't work for 14.04. When I try the later, I receive the following output:
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

As such, this solution works for me. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Steam works as expected from here.

Answer (score -1):

Steam needs to install these additional `i386` packages:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

I want to download the app steam, but I click on the app and the text is 
now what I do to open steam.

You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:

```
libc.so.6
```

and this to click close.

Comment: Not a valid answer. Are you providing a comment or asking another question?