# Can't get Steam to launch with Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, 64-bit, steam

I apologize if this is duplicate, but in over an hour, I can't find any solution that's working for me. I installed Steam from the Software Center but it simply won't start. At first, I was getting this:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

After switching to proprietary drivers for my graphics card, an AMD Radeon HD 6670, I'm now only getting this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
```

The result is the same: Steam doesn't launch and nothing happens.

I'm a within-the-last-48-hours newbie to Linux in general, so I have no clue what to do here. Again, I apologize if this has been asked and answered a million times over, I've just not found anything that fixes the issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the i386 packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the terminal and type in:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

This worked for me. Maybe you can find some more help [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257084/how-do-i-install-steam-on-a-64bit-system/257089#257089).