# Can't install steam

Tags: apt, dpkg, steam

Can someone help me with this problem. Every time I try to install steam I keep getting the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package steam:i386 (--configure):
package steam:i386 is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
steam:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What Ubuntu are you on? How are you installing it (or what commands are you running)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257084/how-do-i-install-steam-on-a-64bit-system

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried to install it the more surely it will be that you have left dependencies then the first thing that you will have to do will be to execute `sudo apt-get remove steam` in case of error because this is not or what it is it goes to the next step that will be to update the list Of repositories with `sudo apt-get update` and after this a  `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove all the dependencies that may be giving problems. After doing all this you can re-run  `sudo apt-get install steam`