# Unable to install Steam because of broken packages

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, steam

I can't install Steam no matter what I try. Dependencieo over dependencies ... you got it.
I tried anything I could, and ended up damaging my system. Now it's like new. Here is the link of tutorial I followed: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-insta...al-fossa-linux

Here is what happens when I execute `sudo apt-get install steam`:

```
techguy@techbook:~/steam$ sudo apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried reconfiguring and adding repositories and anything I could, but that `libgl1-mesa` problem is still there.
I have managed to install steam installer (via .deb) but the problem comes when I launch Steam installer. Here is what happens:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for techguy:
......
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages

Comment: Hey TechTheGuy! The link of the tutorial in your question is not working. Please paste the correct link **in the question**. Paste the output of `apt-cache policy steam libgl1-mesa-dri libtxc-dxtn0 libgl1-mesa-glx libudev1 libgl1 libglx0 libglapi-mesa` **in your question** (not in the comments).

Comment: You may want to check out this solution i marked your question to be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/257089/522934. You need to enable 386 architecture otherwise you will not get packages for it and thus they're  missing.

Comment: Videonauth's duplicate link seems good enough to solve this question, but if it doesn't work the answers to [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/) will give you more options.